# Check for a value in Kotlin immutable list

Tags: kotlin, guava, option-type

I need to condense the following lines in kotlin to a more elegant way. I'm not able to figure out how to check the optional and the values at the same time. Basically I need to verify the list 'a' exists, has one or more items and that they are not 0.

```
val a = Utils.getItems() // returns an Optional<ImmutableList<ItemChange>>
if(!a.orElse(ImmutableList.of()).size > 0) {
  val nonZero = a.get().filter { it.item != BigDecimal.ZERO }
  return nonZero.size > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also want to return false if non-existent or size 0, this is how I'd do it.

The `any` function returns true if any value matches, so it already takes care of the case of an empty list. And it breaks immediately if any match is found, whereas `filter` will exhaustively check the whole List and allocate a new List to hold the results.

Guava Optional can simply be converted to nullable with `orNull()` because Kotlin already has null-safety built in.

```
val items = Utils.getItems().orNull()
return items != null && items.any { it.item != BigDecimal.ZERO }
```